# Can I tint a htmltext img tag in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, htmltext, tint

Can I tint an image from library included in an htmlText in AS3 (using flash cs5)?

On the stage I'd use:

```
var cTint:Color = new Color();
cTint.setTint(0xff00ff, .25);
image.transform.colorTransform = cTint;
```

The htmlText code (cobj.img is a string with the library AS linkage name):

```
op.htmlText = "<img src='"+cobj.img+"' width='40' height='40' vspace='0' />";
```

And if not, is there a way to use an image from stage instead? So I can create an image, put it to stage and then in the htmlText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance from the image, tint it and add that in you text!
Suppose your image is a MovieClip in the library.

```
var libraryImage:MovieClip = new LibraryImage();
var cTint:Color = new Color();
cTint.setTint(0xff00ff, .25);
libraryImage.transform.colorTransform = cTint;

op.htmlText = "<p> </p><img src='libraryImage' width='40' height='40' vspace='0' />";
//add empty string at the start and you dont need to concatenate the string.
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another way of doing it as well. You can apparently set an id of the image by <img src="img" id="imgid"/> and then retrieve the image object by op.getImageReference("imgid"); and then set colorTransfor on that object.